# How to show type information when there is an error squiggel in visual studio [fsharp]

Tags: visual-studio, f#, intellisense

I am writing some FSharp code and if I put my mouse over `Query` in the first line then I see.

[image]

However if I try the same thing with the line with the green squiggel I get

[image]

which is ok because the error/warning is what I would expect. However if I also want to see the type information as in the first image I cannot figure out how to hide the error popup and show the type popup.

In this case the error is easy to fix by assigning the output. In other cases the error can only be fixed if I can see the underlying type with the mouse over but I can't see the type because the error popup takes precedence.

I don't really want a solution where I turn off errors permanently. There must be a shortcut/keycombo to hide the error popup or manually raise the type info popup.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a way <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> <kbd>I</kbd> which is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> then <kbd>I</kbd> by itself, which gets you

[image]

but you really need to do it with the mouse not over the target item

[image]

but this is really bad UX. It would be better if the type info and the error info just appeared together in a tooltip stack by default.